# sticky footer with section stops

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm trying to make the footer fixed until the whole body of the article is not seen on the page using the [ScrollToFixed](https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed) plugin. But it doesn't seem to sticky the right element:

```
$(function(){
    var collection = $('header');
    var offset = 0;
    $.each(collection, function(index, marker) {
        offset += $(marker).parent().offset().top;
        console.log(offset);
        $(marker).scrollToFixed({
            limit: offset,
            bottom: 0
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C8953/1/

It's more like sticky headers with section stops but this time it's the footer. thanks in advance for any tip!

**EDIT**: It kinda works now, but only for the first elememnt:

http://jsfiddle.net/C8953/2/

Answer (score -1):

you can do it by using css only (I have used this code to fix the footer div at the bottom always)

```
< div class="footer" >< / div >
.footer{
    height: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

IE 6 css fix in addition to the above code

```
.footer{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:auto;
    top:expression(eval(document.documentElement.scrollTop+document.documentElement.clientHeight-this.offsetHeight-(parseInt(this.currentStyle.marginTop,10)||0)-(parseInt(this.currentStyle.marginBottom,10)||0)));
}
```

Please remove the excess space in the div code (I don't know how to place HTML code in stackoverlow.com).

Comment: But the footer needs to be shown once the a part of the article is visible while scrolling down.

Comment: You can see the footer always. that means this code fixes the footer in the browsers bottom visible area always.!

Comment: but I don't have a single footer. have you checked fiddle?

Comment: Let me try my best, I'll reply you back soon.